# type object 'ModelDeclarativeMetaclass' has no attribute 'Meta'

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have created resource for one model in django and registered in urls.py
But when I am accessing home page following error crept up.

Error stack:

```
ERROR: Internal server error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/himanshu_office/Envs/ndse/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 98, in get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/home/himanshu_office/Envs/ndse/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 338, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/himanshu_office/Envs/ndse/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 367, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/himanshu_office/Envs/ndse/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 361, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/himanshu_office/projects/NDSE/NDSE/urls.py", line 28, in <module>
    url(r'^questionnaire/', include('questionnaire.urls', namespace='questionnaire')),
  File "/home/himanshu_office/Envs/ndse/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 28, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/himanshu_office/projects/NDSE/NDSE/questionnaire/urls.py", line 8, in <module>
    questionnaire_api_v1.register(questionnaire_resources.SectionResource)
  File "/home/himanshu_office/Envs/ndse/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/api.py", line 54, in register
    resource.__class__.Meta.api_name = self.api_name
AttributeError: type object 'ModelDeclarativeMetaclass' has no attribute 'Meta'
```

file: questionnaire/api/resources.py

```
from tastypie import resources, fields
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from questionnaire import models as questionnaire_models


class SectionResource(resources.ModelResource):
    """
    Resource for Section model with deepest level
    """

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'section'
        queryset = questionnaire_models.Section.objects.all()
        list_allowed_methods = ['get']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get']
        authorization = Authorization()
        always_return_data = True
        include_resource_uri = True
        fields = ['name']
```

file: questionnaire/models.py

```
from jsonfield import JSONField
from sanitizer.models import SanitizedTextField

from django.db import models

from evaluation import models as evaluation_models


class Section(models.Model):
    """
    Model to Store Section which represent collection of questions
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True,
        help_text="Unique name of section to classify questions")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

file: questionnaire/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

from tastypie.api import Api

from questionnaire.api import resources as questionnaire_resources

questionnaire_api_v1 = Api(api_name='questionnaire')
questionnaire_api_v1.register(questionnaire_resources.SectionResource)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^', include(questionnaire_api_v1.urls)),
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I commited mistake while registering api
It should be

```
questionnaire_api_v1.register(questionnaire_resources.SectionResource())
```

in place of:

```
questionnaire_api_v1.register(questionnaire_resources.SectionResource)
```